# $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k(k+1)…(k+m+1)}=\frac{1}{(m+1)\cdot(m+1)!}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Can I proof this identity somehow without using the Riemann integral?

I have tried Stolz–Cesàro Theorem and sums of valuations' progressions.

Comment: Actually I think it's $\dfrac{1}{(m+1)(m+1)!}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that
$$
\frac{1}{k(k+1)\cdots(k+m+1)}=\frac{1}{(m+1)}
\left(\frac{1}{k(k+1)\cdots(k+m)}-\frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)\cdots(k+m+1)}\right).
$$
Thus
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k(k+1)\cdots(k+m+1)}=\frac{1}{(m+1)}
\left(\frac{1}{(m+1)!}-\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(n+m+1)}\right),
$$
and hence
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k(k+1)\cdots(k+m+1)}=\frac{1}{(m+1)\cdot (m+1)!}.
$$

Comment: Not quite...  first of all,
$$ \dfrac{1}{k(k+1)\ldots(k+m+1)} = \dfrac{1}{m+1} \left( \dfrac{1}{k(k+1)\ldots(k+m)} - \dfrac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)\ldots(k+m+1)}\right)$$
Second, note that $$\dfrac{1}{1(1+1)\ldots(1+m)} = \dfrac{1}{(m+1)!}$$

Comment: Perfectly well! I never guess that.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: Corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over k\pars{k + 1}\ldots\pars{k+m+1}}
     ={1 \over m\,m!}:\ {\Large ?}}$

> \begin{align}
> &\color{#00f}{\large\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over k\pars{k + 1}\ldots\pars{k+m+1}}}=
> \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{\Gamma\pars{k} \over \Gamma\pars{k + m + 2}}
> =
> {1 \over \pars{m + 1}!}\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}
> {\Gamma\pars{k}\Gamma\pars{m + 2} \over \Gamma\pars{k + m + 2}}
> \\[3mm]&=
> {1 \over \pars{m + 1}!}\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{\rm B}\pars{k,m + 2}=
> {1 \over \pars{m + 1}!}\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}
> \int_{0}^{1}t^{k - 1}\pars{1 - t}^{m + 1}\,\dd t
> \\[3mm]&=
> {1 \over \pars{m + 1}!}\int_{0}^{1}\pars{1 - t}^{m + 1}
> \pars{\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}t^{k - 1}}\,\dd t
> =
> {1 \over \pars{m + 1}!}\int_{0}^{1}\pars{1 - t}^{m + 1}\,{1 \over 1 - t}\,\dd t
> \\[3mm]&=
> {1 \over \pars{m + 1}!}\bracks{-\,{\pars{1 - t}^{m + 1} \over m + 1}}_{0}^{1}
> =\color{#00f}{\large{1 \over \pars{m + 1}\pars{m + 1}!}}
> \end{align}

$\ds{{\rm B}\pars{x,y} \equiv \int_{0}^{1}t^{x - 1}\pars{1 - t}^{y - 1}\,\dd t}$
is the *Beta Function* which satisfies
$\ds{{\rm B}\pars{x,y} = {\Gamma\pars{x}\Gamma\pars{y} \over\Gamma\pars{x + y}}}$. $\Gamma\pars{z}$ is the *Gamma Function*. Also, $\ds{\Gamma\pars{n + 1} = n!}$
with $\ds{n \in {\mathbb N}}$.

Answer (score 1):

The denominator is $k (k+1)_{m+1}$ where the second term is the Pochhammer symbol.

The summation from $k=1$ to $k=n$ simplifies and write
$$\frac{\frac{1}{\Gamma (m+1)}-\frac{(m+1) \Gamma (n+1)}{\Gamma (m+n+2)}}{(m+1)^2}$$ Going to limit, this seems to give  $$\frac{1}{(m+1)^2 \Gamma (m+1)}$$ which seems to be wrong !

**I would really appreciate if somebody could tell me where I started being wrong.**